# Kendo UI upload file size limit using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using MVC.NET with kendo ui.  I have implemented the kendo UI upload, and it works fine.  However I need to be able to upload a large file, around 200MB.  I updated the maxRequestLength and the executionTimeout properties in my web.config file.
But when I upload a 90MB file, it just waits for a while then errors out, has anyone else managed to upload a large file using kendo ui?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you also updated maxAllowedContentLength? If yes, and the problem is still unresolved, could you post the server response here? (You can catch it using Fiddler)

Comment: Thanks for that.  That worked.  Much appreciated.  Just out of curiosity I have been reading that there might an issue of denial of service attacks by increasing the limits.  Is that true? if it is what is the best way to resolve this?

Comment: That's actually a tricky question. Yes, by default increasing the request limits makes it easier to DoS your service, but if you have to upload large files what alternative do you really have? Sending data over pendrive-carrying pigeons? Uploading the larger files in parts/packages? Thats tricky cross-browser. In a few years we could achieve that by [FileApi](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) (unless you're making something stuff for very limited number of browsers), but now? Some flash-y or java-y or smthing plugin would be required to slice the file into parts.

Comment: so what you are saying is the 1000 pigeons I just purchased was a waste of money? :P.. what about using the following though? Since the maximum request size limit is there to protect your site, it's best to expand the file-size limit for specific directories rather than your entire application. That's possible since the web.config allows for cascading overrides. You can add a web.config file to your folder which just contains the above, or you can use the <location> tag in your main web.config to achieve the same effect?